# Close app after calling smscomposetask

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I tried using the following code but its not working as the app closes immediately without even showing compose message task:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
            smsComposeTask.To = number;
            smsComposeTask.Body = "I'll call you back.";
            smsComposeTask.Show();
            Application.Current.Terminate();
        }
```

Is there a way to close app after this button is clicked and sms task has been completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added a 500ms delay between show task and terminate.
the app went tombstone in this time and couldn't execute terminate statement.

```
smsComposeTask.Show();
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
 Application.Current.Terminate();
```

Comment: This is a poor and a dirty way to achieve what the OP needs. On low-end devices, it might be possible that the Launcher / Task could take more than 500ms to specially if the call is being awaited. This would mean that the application could terminate without launching the Task.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app closed before the separate messaging app starts.
Why do you need to close the app? It's in the tombstoning state if you launch a messaging task (from MSDN):

> Windows Phone applications are not able to directly access common information stores such as the contacts list or to directly invoke other applications such as phoning or messaging. To support scenarios requiring common tasks such as phoning or messaging, the Windows Phone provides a set of launcher and chooser APIs that enables applications to access these useful phone features indirectly. The launcher and chooser APIs invoke distinct built-in applications that replace the currently running application.)

Comment: i want to close app when the sms compose task is completed and the app comes to foreground. somehow this is the requirement of my app.

Comment: In this case you should check   when the app is activated or deactivated( handlers in App.xaml.cs file ) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: But how would i know my app is navigating from sms task.

Comment: I don't think that you can get info about previous launched app. Maybe the best option: save in Button_click info in  application-level or page-level state dictionaries  or in IsolatedStorage that the app must be closed and in Activated handler or NavigatedFrom handler check this flag (if exist, remove it and terminate app)

Comment: i tried this and it worked...smsComposeTask.Show();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Application.Current.Terminate();

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to make a shortcut app and hence you would like the app to close after launching the specified Task.

There's no need to use `Thread.Sleep` as there is a better approach for achieving the same.

You can call your SmsComposeTask in the `App.xaml.cs` file in the `Application_Launching` event

And then call the `Application.Current.Terminate();` when the app is sent to Background in the Deactivated Event (Application_Deactivated)